# Java loop goes 4 times for some reason

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I have this assignment where I need to loop user's input 6 times. the loop, after finishing, looped again for 3 more times. I didn't add a for lop before it so I don't know how to handle it.

Here's the code for the method:

```
public static int[] getPlayerNumbers(int[] playNums) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < playNums.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers from 1-9: " + i);
        playNums[i] = input.nextInt();

        while (playNums[i] < 1 || playNums[i] > 9) {
            System.out.println("Invlaid input. Please only enter 1-9. ");
            playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    return playNums;
}
```

I placed `i` to see the index and it goes `0` to `5` then returns to `0`. I ran out of ideas, please help.

Comment: Please enlighten us what you entered, when the application asked you to enter a number (maybe a screenshot of the application execution?)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. My only guess would be that you call the method in two places.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your playNums has more than 6. try

```
public static int[] getPlayerNumbers(int[] playNums) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers from 1-9: " + i);
    playNums[i] = input.nextInt();

    while (playNums[i] < 1 || playNums[i] > 9) {
        System.out.println("Invlaid input. Please only enter 1-9. ");
        playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}

return playNums;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it seems to work for me. The playsNums contains certainly more than 6 values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] playNums ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        getPlayerNumbers(playNums);
        for (int playNum: playNums) {
            System.out.println(playNum);
        }
    }

    public static int[] getPlayerNumbers(int[] playNums)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < playNums.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers from 1-9: " + i);
            playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
            while (playNums[i] < 1 || playNums[i] > 9) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter 1-9. ");
                playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return playNums;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static int[] getPlayerNumbers(int[] playNums)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
        if(playNums[i] < 1 || playNums[i] > 9){
           System.out.println("Invlaid input. Please only enter 1-9. ");
           getPlayerNumbers(playNums);
        } else{

        System.out.println("Please enter numbers from 1-9: " + i);
            playNums[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
    return playNums;
```